# Flutter Firebase Phone Auth missing-client-identifier

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Once i got my keys with this code on terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

[keystore image]

And I typed my keys into Firebase console and download the json file.

Firebase image

[image: 1]

I moved the Json file to : `android/app/google-services.json`

I am still getting this error.

> [firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a
> valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor
> reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for
> more details.

Solutions for Sha-1 and Sha-256 doesn't work and '`Android Device Verification`' is deprecated in Google Console.

I will be glad if you help.

**I solved the problem:**

Step 1 : use this code again;

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Step 2 : Add firebase console Sha-1 and Sha-256 fingerprints
[image: 1]

Step 3 : go to : https://console.cloud.google.com/

Step 4 :Select your Cloud App

[image: 2]

Step 5 : Edit your Sha-1 Fingerprint on Android restrictions

[image: 3]